# MATLAB - Table - Unnest variable sized cells in table

Tags: matlab, variables, cell, unnest

I tried to unnest a variable sized cell in a table. I get dimension unmatch multiple tries. Here the code (German, just random names):

```
entwicklung = {{'Mueller', 'Schroeder', 'Kuehn'},...
    {'Schulz', 'Wagner'}, ...
    {'Wolf', 'Schwarz', 'Neumann'}};
vertrieb = {{'Braun', 'Zimmermann'},...
    {'Krueger', 'Klein'},...
    {{'Schaefer'}}};
geschfhrng = {{{'Hofmann'}},...
    {'Lange', 'Schmidt'},...
    {{'Peters'}}};
qualitaet = {{'Moeller', 'Kaiser'},...
    {{'Jung'}},...
    {'Friedrich', 'Baumann'}};
doku = {{'Albrecht', 'Winkler'},...
    {'Stein', 'Vogt', 'Ziegler'},...
    {{'Pfeifer'}}};
cellB5 = [entwicklung; vertrieb; geschfhrng; qualitaet; doku];
zeilenbeschriftung = ...
    {'Entwicklung', 'Vertrieb', 'Geschaeftsfuehrung', 'Qualitaet', 'Dokumentation'};  
spaltenbeschriftung = ...
    {'FuenfJahre', 'ZehnJahre', 'FuenfzehnJahre'};
structE2 = cell2struct(cellB5, spaltenbeschriftung, 2);

tabelle7 = cell2table(struct2cell(structE2));
       % tabelle7.Properties
spaltennamen = {'Entwicklung', 'Vertrieb', 'Geschaeftsfuehrung',...
'Qualitaet', 'Dokumentation'};
zeilennamen = {'FuenfJahre', 'ZehnJahre', 'FuenfzehnJahre'};
tabelle7.Properties.VariableNames = spaltennamen;
tabelle7.Properties.RowNames = zeilennamen;
```

Now I want to un-nest the cells in the Table:

```
                  Entwicklung     Vertrieb     Geschaeftsfuehrung    Qualitaet     Dokumentation
                  ___________    __________    __________________    __________    _____________

FuenfJahre        {1×3 cell}     {1×2 cell}    {1×1 cell}            {1×2 cell}    {1×2 cell}   
ZehnJahre         {1×2 cell}     {1×2 cell}    {1×2 cell}            {1×1 cell}    {1×3 cell}   
FuenfzehnJahre    {1×3 cell}     {1×1 cell}    {1×1 cell}            {1×2 cell}    {1×1 cell}
```

To get something similar to this for all rows:

```
                   Entwicklung                        Vertrieb     Geschaeftsfuehrung           Qualitaet            Dokumentation
                  ________________________________    __________    __________________    ________________________    _____________

FuenfzehnJahre    'Wolf'    'Schwarz'    'Neumann'    {1×1 cell}    {1×1 cell}            'Friedrich'    'Baumann'    {1×1 cell}
```

Challenge here is to get the 1x1 cells unpacked as well and to concatenate with the other rows. For Preallocating Issues I tried to find the max of the cells and wanted to create an empty table from this vector und then to fill the empty table with the single rows. Can't get it to work.

with this code:

```
%{
spaltennamen = {'Entwicklung', 'Vertrieb', 'Geschaeftsfuehrung',...
'Qualitaet', 'Dokumentation'};
zeilennamen = {'FuenfJahre', 'ZehnJahre', 'FuenfzehnJahre'};
%}
tabelle12 = tabelle7;
tabellentiefe = size(tabelle7, 1);
maxSpaltenGroessen = max(cellfun(@max, cellfun(@size, tabelle12{:, :},... 
'UniformOutput', false)));
neueZeileLeer = arrayfun(@(x) cell(1, x), maxSpaltenGroessen,...
'UniformOutput', false);
neueTabelleLeerCell = repmat(neueZeileLeer, tabellentiefe, 1);
neueTabelleLeer = cell2table(neueTabelleLeerCell);

tabelle12 = neueTabelleLeer;
tabelle12.Properties.VariableNames = spaltennamen;
tabelle12.Properties.RowNames = zeilennamen;
```

I got this:

```
                    Entwicklung         Vertrieb       Geschaeftsfuehrung    Qualitaet    Dokumentation
                  ______________    ______________    __________________    _________    _____________

FuenfJahre        []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []              []    []     []    []     
ZehnJahre         []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []              []    []     []    []     
FuenfzehnJahre    []    []    []    []    []    []    []    []              []    []     []    []
```

Now I wanna transfer the content of one table "tabelle7" to another one "tabelle12". Any help?

Comment: As long as there is no solution here, Im still on it.

Comment: okay, gave up on this for the time being